# Изменение стиля активного пункта меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть скрипт который выделяет активный пункт меню, но он меняет `background` `<а>`  а мне необходимо чтобы он менял `background` тега `<li>`. Где подправить?

html

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.active {
  background:red;
}
```

js

```
$(function () { 
    $('.menu a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        var link = this.href; 
        if(location == link) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () { 
    $('.menu a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        var link = this.href; 
        if(location == link) {
            $(this).closest("li").addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно одновременно изменить цвет ссылки <a> и background <li>?

Comment: просто после `$(this).addClass('active');` добавьте строчку `$(this).closest("li").addClass('active');` с нужным классом вместо `active`. Т.е. в каждой строке вместо active поставьте нужные классы с нужным background

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () { 
    $('.menu a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        var link = this.href; 
        if(location == link) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```